# Publishing a questionnaire that was used with authorial permission

Tags: plagiarism, copyright, supporting-information

We have used a questionnaire which was designed and used by another research team. We have permission from the researcher in charge of the team to use their questionnaire. Now we want to submit our paper and we intend to put questions in the appendix section of our paper.

I do not know whether it is necessary to make a remark regarding the permission of using that or not? If so, is it enough to mention the reference for that? Moreover, because some journals have similarity check, so I think that we get similarity if we repeat questions in the appendix of out paper. How can this issue be addressed?

Comment: Similarity != plagiarism. Why wouldn't the journal/editor expect similarity in the appendix of a paper that represents questionnaire items credited to another publication? It would be a bit disturbing if they weren't similar, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ethical norms differ by field, but I would think that you should *both* explicitly credit (with a citation if possible) the questionnaire and also thank the designer in the acknowledgements for permission to use it.  The first is a professional obligation to the field to make clear the source of the ideas; the second is a professional obligation to the designer to thank them for allowing you to use it.

Comment: Permission to use an instrument is not the same as permission to publish it in its entirety in your appendix ...

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, that should be an answer. Make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer here is related to only one issue: copyright. Let's assume that the questionnaire you used was an original creative work of the authors, and that the originality and creativity involved in developing the questionnaire were sufficient to bring the questionnaire within the scope of copyright law.

I accept that you obtained the permission of the authors to use the questionnaire in your study. In effect, for copyright purposes, the authors granted you a "license" to *use* the questionnaire. ***But*** ... how broad was the license? Did the license include the right to publish the questionnaire yourself, and did the license include the right to *sub-license* ... in other words, to allow a journal publisher to publish the questionnaire. If you are in any doubt, I suggest that you go back to the authors of the questionnaire and clarify exactly what permissions have been granted to you.

Many journals do in fact publish articles based on copyrighted questionnaires that are inaccessible to most of the journal readers. For example, many readers of psychology journals will be unable to get their hands on a copy of the [Wechsler Intelligence Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wechsler_Adult_Intelligence_Scale), the [Beck Depression Inventory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beck_Depression_Inventory), or any of hundreds of other psychological test instruments. It's a problem for readers, but not necessarily an insurmountable problem for authors.